# Hiding files of a certain extension (.pyc) from all Finder dialogs

Tags: macos, finder

Some file types are already hidden by default in Finder, and in all standard file dialogs in OS X (10.6) already. I would like to add a file type to be hidden: anything with the .pyc extension. If I select 'Get Info' on a .pyc file, there seems to be an option for hiding that file type, but it's disabled/grayed out and I don't know why. Is there any other way to hide them?

Comment: As for your *there seems to be an option for hiding that file type:* if you're referring to the checkbox "Hide extension" in the "Name & Extension" pane, then that would only remove the ".pyc" part from the views. The rest of the file name would still be shown.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I wouldn't normally suggest this...  But you asked...

Assuming Leopard:

```
 find -x /path/to/folder -name \*.pyc -exec chflags hidden {} +
```

Just supply the proper "/path/to/folder".  The drawback is that it has to be done periodically for newly created files. And this also hides file from `ls` in Terminal. From [`man chflags`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html):

> Only a limited number of utilities are `chflags` aware.  Some of these
>   tools include `ls`, `cp`, `find`, `install`, `dump`, and `restore`.

Prior to Snow Leopard, you can try to edit the .hidden file that is in the root of the boot drive.  That contains a list of hidden file types...  But it doesn't exist on my Snow Leopard system, so it may have only existed in 10.4.

Comment: (Added a warning about `ls`...)

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Thank you for the answer.